# MonoGame From Source Directory

Tags: monogame

I ran Protobuild.exe, but no one has mentioned where it outputs to. Does anyone here know where the default folder is suppose to be at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Protobuild.exe generates the Visual Studio projects and solutions for every platform. The solutions are in the root directory, i.e. along Protobuild.exe.

Note that Protobuild does not *build* the framework - you have to open the solution and build it in Visual Studio (which generates its output in `MonoGame.Framework\bin` subdirectory).

Comment: I'm not sure where the projects and solutions are, that's my issue. I've searched for it for far too long and not found anything. Maybe the Protobuild just screwed up badly.

Comment: Nevermind, it did mess up the first time it went through. Thanks.

Comment: "Running Protobuild.exe" requires some explanation, if using Windows OS. 1) Start a `Command Prompt`, so you can see what is going on. 2) `cd` to directory containing `Protobuild.exe`. 3) Type `Protobuild.exe` and return. 4) if get error message, does it say something about can't find `git`?  If so, go to `git-scm.com` and install `git for windows` via option that can be run from Command Prompt. 5) Now when you do step #3, should see a lot of messages `Loading: ...` and `Generating` ... 6) `.sln` files should now appear in the same directory as `Protobuild.exe`, as mentioned in this answer.